# Replacing one element with another in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to replace `inf` with `0` in the matrix, `P`. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
P = np.array([-1.54511316e+12-inf, -1.54511316e+12-inf,-inf,inf,inf])
```

The desired output is:

```
array([-1.54511316e+12, 0, -1.54511316e+12, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`numpy.isfinite`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html):

```
P2 = np.where(np.isfinite(P), P, 0)
```

output:

```
array([-1.54511316e+12,  0.00000000e+00, -1.54511316e+12,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00])
```

Or, for in place modification:

```
P[~np.isfinite(P)] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way, if being sure that we have only `inf`s (not `nan`s), there is another NumPy tool [`np.isinf`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html#numpy.isinf):

```
P[np.isinf(P)] = 0

# [-1.54511316e+12  0.00000000e+00 -1.54511316e+12  0.00000000e+00 
#                   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
```

which is straight forward (exactly for `np.inf`s) and don't need to use *logical not* `~`.